# Simple JSON example with senchaTouch

Tags: json, sencha-touch

I'm trying to achieve a simple JSON operation:

I want to write on my page a text coming from a file in JSON format.

The file is like this: (data.json)

```
{  
     "id": "0",
     "name":"myname"    
}
```

The script is getting the JSON:(main.js)

```
Ext.setup({
onReady: function() {

    Ext.regModel('Person', {
        fields: [
            {name: 'id', type: 'string'},
            {name: 'name', type: 'string'}
        ]
    });

    //I want the  name to be written on the page
    var itemTemplate = new Ext.XTemplate(
        '<tpl for=".">',
         '{name}',
        '</tpl>');

    // I get and decode the Json from data.json   
    var jsonStore = new Ext.data.Store({
        model: "Person",
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'data.json',
            reader: {
                type: 'json'
            }
        },
        autoLoad: true
    });

    // The panel should get the  stored Result and display it    
    var jsonPanel = new Ext.Panel ({
        title: "json",            
        fullscreen: true,         
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'list',
                store: jsonStore,
                itemTpl:itemTemplate,                 
            }
        ]
    });

}
});
```

The `index.html` file calls all the files above and `sencha-touch.js` and `.css`.
I just don't manage to see anything written on the page.

If someone can give me a clue about what i am doing wrong it would help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your JSON objects in array notation, like this:

```
[{
    "id": "0",
    "name":"myname"    
}, {  
    "id": "1",
    "name":"myname2"    
}]
```

Comment: ok the syntax wasnt correct but it wasnt enough to get it working

Comment: I tried here and the example works. Did you put the files into Apache's folder (or another web server) or are you trying to run directly from browser?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can remember (at least that was the case in ST1, I did not try with ST2), the Ajax reader cannot be used to access local files. You need to have your json data delivered through a web server